# What is the best way/module to talk to an Arduino from far away (WIFI)?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, wireless

I am new to Arduino and IoT. I plan to build a product that I will connect to an app and they have to be able to communicate from a very far distance (kilometers).

Bluetooth is not a good option then (because the distance is too far). So would Wifi work? I read something about a module called esp8266 that might be what I am searching for.

Comment: esp8266 can communicate 100's of metres (I've seen claims of over 1km - but that would be with ideal conditions and directional antennas) ESP8266's big brother, the ESP32, has been apparently made to communicate over 10km - again, very ideal conditions and specific equipment required

Comment: Plus add on in esp32 you get Bluetooth but yet it's not having any arduino support for that.

Comment: Alright! A esp32 could be a good solution. I might need it for a bit longer distances though. But thanks a ton for your suggestion

Comment: I'd suggest looking into LORA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esp8266 range is about 400m. So if you have your mobile within 400m then you may be able to communicate. But for long distance communication I would not prefer but if you have any Internet connection available nearby esp then you may be able to transmit your messages via it. Well for long distance communication  I would prefer you to use any GSM shield in which you need to plug in a sim card and it can be used upto when you have coverage in that area.

Comment: Alright! Is is possible for iOS apps to communicate with GSM shields?

Comment: Arduino GSM Shield works the same as a mobile does. It uses the SIM Card to communicate. So as that suggests you can use it send Texts, Call anyone, and use the Data connection to connect to internet. Please refer the [Arduino Page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield)

Comment: Ah alright! I have a sm5100b-d at home that might be what I am searching for

Comment: I don't really now much but I think it might work I am not sure but it might work!

Comment: I don't really now much but I think it might work I am not sure but it might work!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use GSM for the communication. Range isn't an issue, since point A isn't communicating with point B, instead point A and point B are both communicating via third party communication subsystem C which has a much greater coverage than anything you could build yourself.

I use GSM modules for communication with agricultural monitoring and control systems at remote locations. It works well, and you're pretty much guaranteed to have a signal.

For those times when GSM isn't a possibility (no signal, or the customer doesn't want the subscription cost) you really need *line of sight* between the two locations. Then you can use a highly directional antenna (e.g., parabolic dish or Yagi array) to extend any other suitable wireless communication signal over a long range (WiFi can reach tens of kilometres with parabolic dishes) and there are companies that specialise in that kind of equipment (such as [this one that claims 8 mile range](http://www.simplewifi.com/8-mile-antenna.html) - of course you need two of them, one for each end of the link).  Of course, with some skill and determination it's possible to get [incredibly long distances from WiFi](https://www.wired.com/2007/06/w_wifi_record_2/). Not for your average user though...

Comment: appreciate your answer and help a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

**LoRa** is apparently the most popular [low-speed, low-power, wide-area network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPWAN) at the moment.

Many people use LoRa for direct point-to-point links around a kilometer.
Other people use LoRa for "last mile" wireless links as part of a **LoRaWAN** to some gateway hard-wired to the internet, much like a Wifi access point -- except trading off data rates in order to get longer wireless range than WiFi.

details:

- "LoRa is de facto dominant" -- ["LoRaWAN across the globe: LoRa Internet of Things networks overview"](https://www.i-scoop.eu/internet-of-things-guide/iot-network-lora-lorawan/)
- [LoRa range tests](http://forum.anarduino.com/posts/list/46.page) using the RFM95 [Anarduino LoRa Modules](http://www.anarduino.com/?cid=24), similar to the , [LoRa IoT Development Kit](https://www.tindie.com/products/edwin/lora-iot-development-kit/) (using a ["LoRa Bee"](https://www.tindie.com/products/edwin/lora-bee/)), [RFM95W LoRa Module for Arduino](https://www.tindie.com/products/blkbox/rfm95w-915mhz-module-for-arduino/), [RFM95W Breakout Board for LoRa](https://www.tindie.com/products/arduinopraxis/rfm95w-breakout-board-for-lora-applications/), [RFM95 LoRa mikroBUS Module](https://www.tindie.com/products/CascoLogix/rfm95-lora-mikrobus-module/), etc.
- ["LoRa range experiments Urban test"](http://www.hexnut.net/2016/02/lora-range-experiments-urban-test.html) using the Microchip RN2483 module; I can't quite see which breakout board he's using -- I'm guessing it's one of the [Sodaq LoRabee RN2483](https://shop.sodaq.com/en/lorabee-rn2483.html), the [RN2483 LoRa Technology PICtail](https://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=RN-2483-PICTAIL), the [Azzy RN2483 breakout board](https://www.tindie.com/products/DrAzzy/rn2483-breakout-bare-board/), the [Azzy LoRaWAN RN2483/RN2903 Breakout board](https://www.tindie.com/products/DrAzzy/lorawan-rn2483rn2903-breakout-board-assembled/) , etc.
- [The Vinduino](https://hackaday.io/project/6444-vinduino-a-wine-growers-water-saving-project) measures wind and soil moisture using an Arduino and reports back those measurements with a [Globalsat LM-210 LoRa module](https://hackaday.io/project/6444-vinduino-a-wine-growers-water-saving-project/log/39541-lora-network-module-review)
- "LoRaWAN ... Range: 2-5km (urban environment), 15km (suburban environment)" -- 
  ["11 Internet of Things (IoT) Protocols You Need to Know About"](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/eleven-internet-of-things-iot-protocols-you-need-to-know-about)
- [LoRaWAN Part 1: How to Get 15 km Wireless and 10-Year Battery Life for IoT](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2016/nov/lorawan-part-1-15-km-wireless-10-year-battery-life-iot)
- "low power wide area (LPWA) technologies have become popular. In various LPWA technologies, narrowband (NB)-IoT and long range (LoRa) are two leading technologies." -- ["A survey on LPWA technology: LoRa and NB-IoT"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405959517300061)
- "[The LoRa shield: an Open Source Arduino’s long-range communication module](https://www.open-electronics.org/the-lora-shield-an-open-source-arduinos-long-range-communication-module/)" apparently uses the [Open-Electronics LoRa shield for Arduino - Mounted](https://store.open-electronics.org/index.php?_route_=FT1190M)
- ["Building your own private LoRa network"](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/lora-with-mbed/en/latest/intro-to-lora/) mentions several different LoRa shields
- [The LoRa Alliance](https://www.lora-alliance.org/)
- [arduino-lmic](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic): the IBM LMIC (LoraMAC-in-C) library, slightly modified to run in the Arduino environment
- ["LoRa and Long Range Wireless IoT"](https://www.postscapes.com/long-range-wireless-iot-protocol-lora/)
- "The low data-rate (down to few bytes per second) and LoRa modulation lead to ... more than 22km (13.6 miles) in LOS links and up to 2km (1.2miles) in NLOS links in urban environment (going through buildings)." -- ["Extreme Range Links: LoRa 868 / 900MHz SX1272 LoRa module for Arduino Waspmote and Raspberry Pi"](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/extreme-range-lora-sx1272-module-shield-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo/) tested a [SX1272 LoRa module](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/sx1272-lora-module-for-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo-868-mhz) on a Multiprotocol Radio Shield on an Arduino Uno and links to a few other LoRa modules / [LoRaWAN kits](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/shop/wireless/lorawan).